# How to read image in parts (not ImageIO.read())?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Java supports reading of whole images with `ImageIO.read()`, but **is there a way of reading an image only partially?**

Background:

I'm working on a map application that reads large images, splits them up, then uses the generated tiles as the background of a map. In some cases the provided image can be so large that reading the Image as a `BufferedImage` might already cause an `OutOfMemoryError`.

I'm aware I could grant the VM more heap space, still I'd prefer a way to further reduce the risk by reading the image only in parts, i. e. in tiles of 256*256 pixels, that I could save straight away to the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a long time since I've used it but you can do it with JAI (Java Advanced Imaging) using a *TiledImage*.

[JAI homepage.](http://java.net/projects/jai/)

Comment: I've found this API before, but telling from `TiledImage`'s documentation it seems to offer only a view on an image (` RenderedImage` in this case) that *has to be preloaded*. 

And my intention is *not* to preload it, but to read the image in lines or blocks, as if I was using an Iterator.

Is this possible with the JAI? To me it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Seems like you're doing exactly the kind of work I was doing several years ago. I had to extract image pixels from raw satellite data. In some formats the pixels were at a constant offset one from another, in other the offset was variable. I used JAI to read one "line" at a time and display the image progressively on screen. Unfortunately I don't remember exactly which classes I used, but I certainly used JAI to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using PNG format, this library lets you load an image line by line, so you don't need to load it fully in memory http://code.google.com/p/pngj/